# Генератор однотипного кода в NPM

Tags: javascript, npm

Есть ли в NPM что-то похоже на scaffold в RubyOnRails?

Comment: Например `yeoman` есть :)

Comment: Насколько я понял yeoman генерирует все приложение?! А мне хочется что бы создавались лишь некоторые файлы. Например: пишу в консоли gen component Search и в папке Components создается файл Search.js с содержимом React-компонента.

Comment: дак вот же https://github.com/newtriks/generator-react-webpack например: `yo react-webpack:component my/namespaced/components/name`. Хотя я написал свои `live templates` и в IDE гораздо удобнее работать с ними :) Тут я тебе скажу так, люди пишут свои генераторы для себя, так проще синтаксически работать с кодом. А пример можешь взять из репы, которую я скинул

Comment: Вот то, что тебе нужно https://github.com/banderson/generator-flux-react